# Phonegap + JQM: problems with local files on android

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I know this is common question, but I having a hard time understanding
my results based on the various answers I have seen.

I have an phonegap + jquery mobile application that is using several local html files.  The
hierarchy looks like this

```
index.html
  |
  --- A.html  (uses getJSON() to server to get list)
  |     |
  |     --- A1.html  (uses getJSON() to server to get details)
  |
  --- B.html  (uses getJSON() to server to get list)
        |
        --- B1.html    (uses getJSON() to server to get details)
```

html and js assets are local.  I am using jquery mobile.

Everything works fine on blackberry.  On android, index.html, A.html,
and B.html work fine.  When trying to access the details views A1 and
B1, I get "Error Loading Page".

I can't understand why A and B work, but A1 and B1 don't.

Although not sure why this would make a difference, from another
thread I found a suggestion to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

to the activity in the manifest.  This didn't change anything.

In case it is jquery related, I tried adding the following:

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
});
```

Still no love.  Any ideas on how to fix or debug this?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

"Error Loading Page" means that jQuery Mobile could not find the document, which probably means that you are using relaitve URLs and they are getting messed up by the base-url. Try using absolute URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I tried "file:///android_asset/www/A1.html" with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to a webview bug that causes an error when passing data in the URL.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

The URL from A to A1 looks like A1.html?id=1 where the ?id=1 is causing the problem.

Cheers.